# Почему XOR сумма элементов массива равняется отрицательному числу?

Tags: java

Имеются такие элементы массива:

```
2147483648
2147483648
2147483648
2147483648
2147483648
2147483648
2147483648
2147483648
2147483649
```

Их XOR сумма равняется `-2147483647`. Почему ответ именно такой? Никак не могу понять.
Тип данных элементов массива `Long` 
Вот код со сложением элементов:

```
for(int i = 0; i < inputArray.size(); i++) {
    result ^= inputArray.get(i);
}
```

Я думал, что одинаковые элементы должны обратиться в ноль и ответом являлось бы число `2147483649`

Comment: начальное значение result ?

Comment: @AzizUmarov При создании присвоил ноль

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При создании переменной `result` не было присвоено значение, следовательно, она приняла значение `0` и Вы произвели XOR с ней

Можно изменить так:

```
long result = inputArray.get(0);
for(int i = 1; i < inputArray.size(); i++) {
    result ^= inputArray.get(i);
}
```